# Handling environment variables for tests in stage vs production

Tags: detox

I came across Detox's advance mocking on their github repository which led to some confusion. My concern might be already be solved by our devops team but I would like to still ask here. Their documentation state that mocking can be important especially when you would like handle different endpoints (localhost vs production endpoint), however why is this actually important if our application internally handles this. Locally we detect the environment depending on which command the user runs the react-native application with and everything is setup for our environment to run. Additionally in circleci we also setup our environment variables so the application is aware of what endpoints to use.

If anyone can clarify why we need to implement this in detox as well it would be greatly appreciated.

For example

endpoint.js

```js
module.exports = {
 LOGIN_ENDPOINT : ENV === 'sandbox' ? "http://localhost:8080" : "http://api.web.com"
}
```

endpoint.e2e.js (why is this necessary)

```js
module.exports = {
 LOGIN_ENDPOINT : "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

Some references here:

> Mocking is an important part of testing. You may want to alter some 
>   behavior of your app during test and replace it with a mock. Here are > some example reasons why this could be useful:
>
> **Change server endpoints to point to a mock/staging server instead of 
>   the regular production server**

Source: https://github.com/jhen0409/detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md

Video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dy8VP02quMs&feature=youtu.be&t=13m16s

1. I have already setup my environment variables inside my react-native project
2. I have already setup my environment variables inside circleci